# bitwise operators in C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have written a code for swapping bit positions(source bit and destination bit).. it is working fine.. But is there any optimized code to do this?

```
int bit_swap(int num, int sbit, int dbit)
{
if(num & (1 << sbit) == num & (1 << dbit))
return num;
else
return (num ^ ((1 << sbit) | (1 << dbit)));
}
```

Here.. num is the input number.. sbit is the source bit position and dbit is the destination bit position..

Is there any way to write this code in a single line without using **if** and **else**

Comment: Have you profiled? Have you profiled as-is without the `if`?

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR

Comment: @leppie: the article is too good.. helped me a lot.. thanks a ton! :)

Comment: For a swap operation, both bits are both source and destination, thus naming one as source and the other as destination is misleading. Better name them `pos1` and `pos2` or something similar, as given in some answers. Additionally, it is usually a good idea to use unsigned ints when handling single bits, at least if you want your code to be portable. But this depends on what you need this for, just be aware that you may run into problems with negative values.

Comment: I would advise turning up the warning level to start with, clang reports: `& has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]` in `if(num & (1 << sbit) == num & (1 << dbit))`.

Comment: Prior optimizing, make it work. E.g. (255 & (1<<1)) != (255 & (1<<3)) resulting both bits being zeroed. Using xormask (1<<a)^(1<<b) will help to solve the case where a==b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No conditional version.

```
int bit_swap(int num, int sbit, int dbit)
{
    int sval = !!(num & (1 << sbit));  // sets to 1 iff the s-bit is already set
    int dval = !!(num & (1 << dbit));  // sets to 1 iff the d-bit is already set

    int xorval = (sval ^ dval); // sets to 1 if (sval != dval), otherwise 0

    // so if xorval is 1, then it will toggle the bits at the S and D positions
    // otherwise, the expression below evalutes to "num" that was passed in
    return (num ^ ((xorval << sbit) | (xorval << dbit)));
}
```

Comment: This code has undefined behavior if `sbit` or `dbit` indicates the highest bit in an `int` in typical C implementations, because `1 << sbit` or `1 << dbit` overflows the values of a signed `int`. Generally, it is better to use unsigned integers for bit operations like this.

Comment: Undefined only if (sbit < 0) || (sbit >= (sizeof(int)*8) will there be a problem. (Same for dbit). Assuming 32-bit, 31 is the MSB index.  (1 << 31) is 0x80000000 and will not overflow. Bit shifting left is ok for signed int, but is undefined for right-shifts.  There's no right-shifts above.

Comment: 1<<31 is an overflow with a 32-bit `int`. C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.7 4: “If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1*2**E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.” The value 2**31 is not representable in a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Interesting. I just looked at the spec you cited. I knew about the undefined behavior of right-shifting a signed-negative int, but not the left-shift behavior. However, I suspect the world would tip upside down if (1<<31) wasn't 0x80000000 (on a 2's complement machine).

Comment: It is a trap to think that the machine works a certain way, so the C semantics follow along. One of the things that happens is that C rules are built into the optimizer in various ways, and it makes perfectly legal but unexpected deductions. Once the optimizer deduces that a certain piece of code evaluates `1<<31`, it can do anything it wants, like completely eliminating all code that flows to that evaluation (after observable effects before it) and all code that flows from it.

Comment: No disagreement. Changing to use unsigned variables during shifting would be correct - but it won't change the generated object code at all (*for the machines I know about*). But your point is **very well taken**.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just write `sval = (num>>sbit) & 1` ? Still one shift, one AND, but no !!. Next, you can move both `&1` to after `xorval = sval^dval` as the last bit of xorval depends only on the last bits of sval and dval.

Comment: I.e. just `unsigned xorval = ((num>>sbit) ^ (num>>dbit)) & 1;`

Comment: @MSalters - my goal on that answer was to just demonstrate that bitswapping can be accomplished without a branch. I went for readability instead of compactness.  In any case, I also encourage you to compile your solution and my version of that function together in the same program (gcc yours.c mine.c main.c -O3) on Intel. Then gdb a.out and do a "disassemble swapBits" and "disassemble bit_swap".  The length of assembly generated for each may surprise you.

Answer (score 12):

You are making the classical mistake in thinking that less lines in C means more optimised code.

You should really examine the assembler output and profile your code to see if it's an actual bottleneck.

What I tend to do is optimise for *readability* first then only attack performance if it becomes an issue. So, a more readable solution (in my not so humble opinion) would be something like:

```
unsigned int bit_swap (unsigned int num, unsigned int pos1, unsigned int pos2) {
    // Swapping identical bit positions is a no-op.

    if (pos1 == pos2)
        return num;

    // Get masks from bit positions.

    unsigned int mask1 = 1 << pos1;
    unsigned int mask2 = 1 << pos2;

    // Get bit truth values.

    int bit1_was_set = ((num & mask1) != 0);
    int bit2_was_set = ((num & mask2) != 0);

    // Clear and set first bit (set only if second bit was originally set).

    num = num & ~mask1;
    if (bit2_was_set)
        num = num | mask1;

    // Do the same for other bit.

    num = num & ~mask2;
    if (bit1_was_set)
        num = num | mask2;

    // Return the value with swapped bits.

    return num;
}
```

Despite having far more lines than your approach, you may well find the insanely optimising compilers available nowadays will give you similar code under the covers.

What you almost certainly *will* discover is that non-C-guru people (and possibly yourself, six months from now) will be able to understand your source code better than a single line multi-bitwise-operator variant.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with

```
unsigned swapBits(unsigned num, int sbit, int dbit)
{
  return ( num &               // All bits
    ~((1<<sbit) | (1<<dbit)))  // Except sbit and dbit
    | (((num>>sbit)&1)<<dbit)  // but with sbit moved to dbit
    | (((num>>dbit)&1)<<sbit); // and with dbit moved to sbit
}
```

I did have an ARM in mind, with its cheap shifts.

Comment: nice one.. was expecting this kinda answer.. :)